# When I try to connect to mongodb in the command prompt it will display an error how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

```
  ^
```

MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect 
[MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

```
at Pool.<anonymous>
```

(C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\meanapp\server\node_modules\mongodb-

core\lib\topologies\server.js:328:35)

```
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)

at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)

at Connection.<anonymous>
```

(C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\meanapp\server\node_modules\mongodb-

core\lib\connection\pool.js:274:12)

Comment: Have you started the MongoD Service before connecting?

Comment: nope   I write the following code
mongose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meanapp');
mongose.connection.once('open',function() {
    //Load the models

    console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
    app.listen(3000);

});

Comment: nope I just write the code as                                                                                             //Connect to MongoDB
mongose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meanapp');
mongose.connection.once('open',function() {
    //Load the models

    console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
    app.listen(3000);

});

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the connection have been refused (ECONNREFUSED). There is no endpoint listening on 127.0.0.1:27017

Mongo have a client-server architecture. Before connecting to the database, you need to start the database server. First, create a folder to store the data files. Then, from command prompt, go to where your mongo installations resides and write:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\path_to_data_folder
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Comment: Im using means stack so first I run the commant nmp install mongoose --save after that what is the next step

Comment: If you are going to use a local mongo database (127.0.0.1) first step is to install mongo locally in your machine. Download it from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community  And second, after installing mongo, start mongod server as per my answer. After those steps, you can connect to your mongo instance.